# "Bold Text" affects autolayout calculations?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiimageview, uiimage

A very strange problem occurred when I use autolayout to constrain my views.
[image]

The icon's (in the red rectangle) width and height are both constrained to 36 pt as shown in the bottom right corner. But the bounds resolved by the autolayout engine equals to (0, 0, 37, 37).

The only happens when the "Bold Text" option is set.
[image]

When "Bold Text" option is off, this problem disappears.

Comment: Well, it does matter. It's 1 pt, not 1 pixel, which means 3 pixels on iPhone 12 or 2 pixels on iPhone 7.

Comment: And, if you take a look a the three images below the icon view. The first image's left edge is beyond its super view's bounds by 1 pixel.